# Can I create an instance to spans multiple computer node?

Tags: cloud, openstack, eucalyptus, opennebula

My question is:

Is there any way to create an instance to spans multiple computer nodes?
It means:

suppose I have two computer nodes, that the first one have 2GB‌ RAM, 20GB HARD and 2 core, the second one have 4GB RAM, 30GB HARD and 4 core. Now I want to create an instance that have 5GB RAM, 45GB HARD and 5 core.

This question is about cloud computing. please answer this question in all cloud computing infrastructure tools: `openstack` , `cloudstack` , `opennebula` , `Eucalyptus` .

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The maximum a virtual machine can have, is what the 'biggest' node can provide (in your case 4GB RAM, 30GB Disk and 4 cores).

Answer (score 0):

You may use overcommitment/overprovisioning to create larger VMs than you're physically able to run, but it will never be able to consume more memory than what you have available on a single compute host, nor combine the resources from multiple hosts into a single vm.